# How to see ALL installed programs and software on a computer remotely or locally

Tags: powershell, registry, scanning

I have seen many posts about PowerShell scripts or commands that allow you to see some of the software installed on a machine. But none that actually show you everything. As i have used it on my computer as well as remote users and i notice with many of these commands its missing a good chunk of the installed software.

Some of the many many commands i have used are:  (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName) (enter-pssession -ComputerName $InstalledSoftware = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
foreach($obj in $InstalledSoftware){write-host $obj.GetValue('DisplayName') -NoNewline; write-host " - " -NoNewline; write-host $obj.GetValue('DisplayVersion')} )

and various others. Basically if you will find it on the first few pages of google i have probably used it or tried to use it. So if anyone has any script that can really look at all software installed on a machine using PowerShell i would love to try it. Otherwise any way to remotely check for all software that is currently installed on a computer is welcome.

I have tried every command or script that i can find on google to try and get PowerShell to pull a list of all programs installed on a computer, i have not found a single command that dose more than list what's in the registry, or programs installed with the computers image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
This is a forum where coders voluntarily help other coders with their challenges. ;-) There are some rules and best practices helping you to get the most out of SO. 
First you may take the [Tour] to get an overview and then you may stop by on [ask]. 
To make it easier for others willing to help you to actually help you you should always [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly and provide a [mre]. 
 ;-)  So you're unsatisfied with the solutions you've found. What did you miss then? `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: [This blog post](https://xkln.net/blog/please-stop-using-win32product-to-find-installed-software-alternatives-inside/) has excellent background information and code that I think does what you're looking for, in the form of a `Get-InstalledApplications` function. It is nontrivial, because it involves examining the registry not just for the _current_ user, but _all_ users.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).