# PowerShell uninstall script

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to remove an application from multiple users computers remotely. The closest i have found to this script wise is the script below (had to remove script due to formatting limitations... sorry). The main issue i see with it is that it uses Win32_Product, but based off what i have seen an heard this will not find apps that are not detected by the OS or the registry. In other words small apps that users have installed by themselves may not be detected.

I have not tried anything yet, as i have been unable to find a script that seems like it would meet my needs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
This is a forum where coders voluntarily help other coders with their challenges. ;-) There are some rules and best practices helping you to get the most out of SO. 
First you may take the [Tour] to get an overview and then you may stop by on [ask]. 
To make it easier for others willing to help you to actually help you you should always [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly and provide a [mre].  ;-) Have a nice day! ... and BTW: You forgot to ask a question. So what's your actual question?

Comment: ... and how is this question any different from this: [How to see ALL installed programs and software on a computer remotely or locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76038718/how-to-see-all-installed-programs-and-software-on-a-computer-remotely-or-locally)

Comment: Is it an msi or programs install?  For a programs install, the silent uninstall command is custom.  For msi you can use uninstall-package.  For a per user install, I would run it as a login script.

Comment: Can you point to the URL the script is from, so we can read it?